# Flatten and combine field from nested struct

Tags: rust, struct, iterator, nalgebra

I have a struct body struct that contains planet info such as position velocity etc

```rust
pub struct Body {
    pub id: u8,
    pub pos: Vec<f64>,
    pub vel: Vec<f64>,
}

pub struct Data {
    pub system_vec: Vec<Body>,
}
```

To put all the pos/vel vecs into a nalgebra matrix I need to first flatten all the body
vecs into an iterator I can feed to the nalgebra api.

```rust
let ncols: &usize = &self.system_vec.len();
let temp_vec = &data.system_vec
                    .iter()
                    .map(|body| body.pos.clone())
                    .collect::<Vec<Vec<f64>>>()
                    .into_iter()
                    .flatten()
                    .collect::<Vec<f64>>();

na::OMatrix::<f64, U3, Dyn>::from_iterator(
    *ncols, 
    temp_vec.iter().cloned()
)
```

My question is this seems to be incredibly over engineered. I'm iterating and then collecting and then iterating again.
I'm sure there is a better way but I'm quite new to rust so this is the best I've got so far.
Is there a more efficient way to get a cloned version of this data into the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a more streamlined solution -

```
let temp_vec = &self.system_vec
               .iter()
               .flat_map(|body| body.pos.clone().into_iter())
               .collect::<Vec<f64>>();
```

Comment: If you know that length of `body.pos` is the same for all bodies (which I assume it is, and that it's 3), you can preallocate memory for `temp_vec`, by creating `Vec::with_capacity(n_bodies * n_pos)` and instead of `collecting`, [extending](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend) it from the iterator. This will make you allocate memory only once, and you won't have to pay for the cost of reallocation vector.

Comment: Rather than clone the Vec (which may get optimized away, but who knows) you can probably do `.flat_map(|body| body.pos.iter()).copied().collect()`.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I've ended up leaving temp_vec as an iter (no collect) and not converting to vec since nalgebra takes an iterator in. And If I recall iterators are lazy so there shouldn't be doubling handling anymore?

Comment: @BallpointBen Thanks, this also works! Although I'm still unclear on the difference

Comment: @thefrollickingnerd My solution is basically equivalent to a nested for loop, `for body in &self.system_vec { for x in &body { ... } }`, which does not allocate any additional memory. Cloning Vecs does allocate additional memory, and needlessly so.

Comment: @thefrollickingnerd `body.pos.clone().into_iter()` will **copy** the whole vector buffer, and yield it's elements. `body.pos.iter().copied()` will **borrow** vector and when yielding instead of returning a reference to it's elements it will **copy** the elements itself (which for `f64` is very cheap). Note that if you want to _return_ such iterator it will be valid only for the lifetime of `&self`, which can be a little finicky.